# if one byte has leaked in a page of 4kb in physical ram,then after swapping to disk does it will count as 4kb is used instead of one byte?

Tags: memory, c++, memory-leaks

We have an 64 bit application running on windows, for the fact we know it is leaking very few bytes of memory in the c++ code.But for a setup which has 16gb physical ram and 32gb pagefile.sys. Resource monitor is showing commit memory as 22gb and 900 MB in working set used by our process.

I knew for every process os will create virtual address space in pages and that number of addresses that will be depend on the 32 bit or 64 bit .I also knew that os will swap pages to disk i.e. pagefile.sys for running other apps.In windows i think page size is 4kb, **what i want to know is if one byte has leaked in a page of 4 kb in physical ram , then after swapping to disk does it will show as 4kb is used instead of one byte by the process or not ?**

Comment: If the OS writes a page to swap file, then one page of swap space will be used. If the applications leaks a byte, that probably means that page won't be returned to the OS, but  the rest of the page will be used by the application.

Comment: As per your above comment i understand if 1 byte is leaked then whole page i.e size of 4 KB is used, because leaked page cannot be given to OS. Now for example before  leaking, in resource monitor,  process memory commit  is showing as 100 KB .After leaking of 1 KB in commit memory ,does it will show 101 KB or 104 KB ?